# javascript get images from list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

```
<ul class="">
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
</ul>
```

i have good knowledge of jquery i know i can do it with that using children or find or directly..but i wana learn javascript and wana do it with js..
i want to select image tag from all the list but m unable to do it can you please explain in briefly.with that i wana learn js as soon as possible for job change can you help in that..

my tried code

```
var i;     
var parent = document.getElementById('right');
var lis = par.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(i=0;i<lis.length;i++){
//wat to do here

}
```

Comment: code will b 
ul > li*5 > images

Answer (score 0):

You need some changes like,

```js
var i;
var parent = document.getElementById('right');
var lis = parent.children;
for (i = 0,l=lis.length; i < l; i++) {
  //wat to do here
  // getting alt for example
  console.log(lis[i].children[0].getAttribute('alt'));
}
```

```html
<ul id="right">
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="3" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="4" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="5" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="6" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="7" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Another option by tag name in `ul` like,

```
var parent = document.getElementById('right');
var lis = parent.getElementsByTagName('img'); // get img tags in ul
for (i = 0,l=lis.length; i < l; i++) {
  //wat to do here
  // getting alt for example
  console.log(lis[i].getAttribute('alt'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the images inside parent and iterate over them.

[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('#right img');
// Get all the images

// Iterate over all the images
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  // Update individual image
  if (images[i].width < 400) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="right">
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is i have a code like this
<div id="someid">

<p><img src="" alt/></p>

<p><img src="" alt/></p>

<p><img src="" alt/></p>

<p><img src="" alt/></p>

<img src="" alt/>

<img src="" alt/>

<img src="" alt/>

</div>
and i want to select images only from p element

Comment: You can use `document.querySelectorAll('#someid p img')`, to `querySelectorAll` you can pass the CSS selectors

Comment: yeah it has select images in array now just trying to take its width and do some thing if width is less than 400

Comment: @DeepakSabharwal Check the updated code, I've added an `if` condition

Comment: thanks @tushar..i think i should take classes from you :D

by the way i was trying like this but got stuck    var im = document.querySelectorAll('#right p img')
console.log(im)
for(var i=0;i<im.length;i++){
 //alert(im[i].offsetWidth)
 var wid = im[i].offsetWidth;
 if (wid < 400){
  
 }
 else {
  
 }
}

Comment: but i have one small issue queryselectorAll dnt have much support cant we do it using for loop

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<ul class="parent">
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""/></li>
</ul>
```

js:

$element = document.querySelector('.parent');

```
var childs = $element.children;
for (var i = 1; i < childs.length - 1; i++)
{
        console.log(childs[i].querySelector('img'))
}
```